# Save command output to file

Tags: windows-7, windows, python, cmd.exe

I want to run this command on my Windows 7:

`python Test.py`

and save its results to text file. Is there any way to do that? I tried this approach: `python Test.py > results.txt`,`results.txt` is created, but stays empty.

Can you give me any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try `python Test.py >> results.txt` and check your results please.

Comment: Yep. Same when I write `python Test.py`

Comment: Blank screen or some outputs? when it is running it manually?

Comment: It gives me output. This is same situation, as when I run that with `python`

Comment: Please check whether the python is set with environmental variable. So that the python is detected in the command prompt. Check how to add environmental variable for python from the following link: Please refer 'Cameron' post in the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621255/how-do-i-run-a-python-program-in-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7